# You have multiple authentication backends configured Django?

Tags: python, django

I am having this error

```
You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user.
```

in my Login class base view in Django

**Login View**

```
class SystemLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = "registration/login.html"
    authentication_form = LoginForm


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        db_name = request.POST['year']
        branch = request.POST["branch"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user and user.active:
            period_id = AccountingPeriod.objects.all()
            if period_id:
                request.session["period_id"] = period_id[0].id
            else:
                request.session["period_id"] = None
                messages.error(
                    request,
                    _(
                        "Please You must Be initial the Period Before Any Operation"
                    ),
                )
            set_defualt(
                request.session.session_key,
                int(branch),
            )
            request.session["branch_id"] = branch

            cache.set("branch", branch)
            list_branch = []
            for x in user.user_branch.all():
                dict_data = {"id": x.pk, "name": x.name}
                list_branch.append(dict_data)
            request.session["user_branch"] = list_branch
            request.session["db_name"] = db_name
            request.session["permission"] = get_all(request)
            request.session["permission_partion"] = get_all_partion(request)
            request.session["db_name"] = db_name
        return super(SystemLoginView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Login Form class**

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm, IttechForm):
    CHOICE = [(x, x) for x in DATABASES]
    year = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=CHOICE,
        label=_("Year"),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
    )
    branch = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Branch.objects.all(),
        label=_("Branch"),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
    )
    username = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Username"),
        max_length=20,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": _("Username"), "class": "form-control"}),
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("password"),
        max_length=30,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder": _("Password"), "class": "form-control"}),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        branch = self.cleaned_data.get("branch")

        backend = ModelBackend()
        user = backend.authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
        if not user:
            raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
        if not user.active:
            self.confirm_login_allowed(user)
        if branch:
            if not user.user_branch.all().filter(id=branch.pk):
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    _("Sorry,This user can't login in this branch")
                )
        return self.cleaned_data

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Sorry,This user was not active contact admin to solve this problem.",
                code='inactive',
            )
```

When the user in authenticated and active it gives me the error above.

please help me solving this.
I have tried a lot of the solutions that are in the internet be none does help me and also i have added the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in my settings.py file but that does not work.

Comment: Can you post your `settings.py`

Comment: ```AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",  # this is default
    "guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend",
)AUTH_USER_MODEL = "permission.UsersDetiles"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem
just added this line of code before calling super.

```
login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
return super(SystemLoginView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and everything just works fine.